# Is there a way i can get CDP neighbors via SNMP in a c# program

Tags: c#, networking

I'm trying to make a c# application to get neighbors of a specific device. Can i send a SNMPGET with an OID to get back its neighbors?

Comment: Why not just PING.

Comment: I need to discover entire network and i do that hop by hop. First i get the default gateway and  see its neighbors to go on, hop by hop. If i ping all addresses on all gateway interfaces takes too long

Comment: CDP is proprietary to Cisco, so you would only get Cisco devices in return, and only those that actually have CDP enabled and enabled on the directly connected interface. Also, the Cisco devices would need to be configured for SNMP (not the default).

Comment: This is a project a work on and the network is totally configured by myself. All devices are cisco and snmp, cdp configured.

Comment: See following : http://based585.rssing.com/chan-7081493/all_p10.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this would help somebody, i found the answer. I've done a snmpwalk with this oid 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.4, and this returned all ip addresses of neighbors in hexadecimal format.

Comment: yep that is the cdpCacheTable but I have found that not all Cisco switches (or perhaps firmwares) support it unfortunately.